# update magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 with composer "no matching package found."

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I run magento community edition 2.3.2 on ubuntu 16.04
I would like to upgrade magento there in order to migrate to a newer ubuntu server and there upgrade to the latest magento version.

In the magento root folder I try to:
sudo php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer update "--no-plugins"

and I get this:

---

```
Key prefer-stable is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 75
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.1.3].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.1.3].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.3 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.1.0].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.3 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.1.0].
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.3].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

---

I run this composer version: Composer version 2.2.21

and here is my composer.json file:

---

```
 "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.3.2",
        "splendidinternet/mage2-locale-de-de": "1.54.0",
        "apptrian/facebook-pixel": "2.2.3",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.3",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~1.0.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.14",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    },
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

---

Thanks a lot for any advice !

PS: PHP 7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2.3.3 does not support composer version 2 yet. You should use composer version 1 or search for a workaround for composer version 2 with Magento 2.3.

You can switch to composer version 1 with the following command:

```
composer self-update --1
```

As you mentioned, you want to upgrade Magento version to the latest version, at this time, Magento 2.4.6(-p1) is the latest version. This version requires PHP 8.1/8.2.

I have written a detailed guide for upgrading Magento 2 from an older version to 2.4.4 or 2.4.5 or 2.4.6, which you can take a look at: https://magetu.com/how-to-upgrade-to-magento-version-2-4-6-or-2-4-5-or-2-4-4/

Related documents:

- System requirements for Magento 2.4.x: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html
- System requirements for Magento 2.3.x: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html